# Fatal error: Uncaught Error: Call to a member function get() on null in registry Class

Tags: php

I have this class for registry class:

```
namespace App\Core;

final class Registry {
    private $data = array();

    /**
     * @param   string  $key
     * 
     * @return  mixed
     */
    public function get($key) {
        return (isset($this->data[$key]) ? $this->data[$key] : null);
    }

    /**
     * @param   string  $key
     * @param   string  $value
     */ 
    public function set($key, $value) {
        $this->data[$key] = $value;
    }

    /**
     * @param   string  $key
     *
     * @return  bool
     */
    public function has($key) {
        return isset($this->data[$key]);
    }

}
```

and this  main Controller:

```
namespace App\Core;
use App\Core\Registry;

abstract class Controller {
    protected $registry;

    public function __construct($registry) {
        $this->registry = $registry;
    }

    public function __get($key) {
        return $this->registry->get($key); //error line
    }

    public function __set($key, $value) {
        $this->registry->set($key, $value);
    }
}
```

and need to get value in index controller:

```
namespace App\Catalog\Controller;

class IndexController extends \App\Core\Controller {

    public function __construct()
    {
    }

    public function index(){
        $this->db->query();
    }
}
```

and in db class:

```
namespace App\Core;

class Db {

    public function __construct()
    {
    }

    public function query(){
        echo 'Im query';
    }
}
```

Now In main index i add :

```
require '../vendor/autoload.php';

$registry = new App\Core\Registry();
use App\Core\Db;
$registry->set('db', new Db());
```

In action i need to print `Im query` from `Db` class But I see This error:

> Fatal error: Uncaught Error: Call to a member function get() on null in /Applications/MAMP/htdocs/mvc/application/Core/Controller.php:16 Stack trace: #0 /Applications/MAMP/htdocs/mvc/application/Catalog/Controller/IndexController.php(13): App\Core\Controller->__get('db') #1 [internal function]: App\Catalog\Controller\IndexController->index() #2 /Applications/MAMP/htdocs/mvc/application/Core/System/Route.php(649): call_user_func_array(Array, Array) #3 /Applications/MAMP/htdocs/mvc/application/Core/System/Route.php(599): App\Core\System\Route->callback(Array, Array) #4 /Applications/MAMP/htdocs/mvc/public/index.php(63): App\Core\System\Route->end() #5 {main} thrown in /Applications/MAMP/htdocs/mvc/application/Core/Controller.php on line 16

Note: I load all class using composer PSR-4 like this:

```
  "autoload": {
    "psr-4": {"App\\": "application/"}
  }
```

how do can in fix this error?!

Comment: In the IndexController you have overridden the __construct method. So how are you passing the registry to controller? If registry is passed only will get the values.

Comment: @HariKT: your mean is remove `__construct` from `IndexController` ?!

Comment: Yes because you are not doing anything in the constructor nor calling the parent constructor with the registry values. What you did in index.php is creating the registry object. Now on the App\Core\System\Route you either want to pass this registry to it. I don't have more code here to tell you. But debug each line which will help you explore how to resolve this. If you get some time I recommend you reading https://daylerees.com/php-pandas/ .